# Unable to import my own Java package into another package of the same project

Tags: java, android

I am facing a strange problem related to `accessing packages`. Recently I merged code of multiple projects into a single one. I reorganized class references, import statements and everything is fine and its working perfectly. But one problem occurred where I am not able to import any package into a specific package.

I try to explain with a simple example:

I had 3 projects

- Draw
- Record
- Capture

and there packages as given below:

```
package com.company.draw;
package com.company.record;
package com.company.capture;
```

Now after merging into single project I am unable to import `com.company.record` or `com.company.capture` into `com.company.draw`, whereas the other packages `com.company.record` and `com.company.capture` can import any of the mentioned packages.

What could be the problem in a specific package which prevents it from accessing other packages?

Comment: Can you post the tree structure of source folder ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you show us a scrrenshot from eclipse package explorer?

Comment: Have you checked the access specifiers?

Comment: Do you try use "clean", let it to reset memory

Comment: It simply gives error: The import can not be resolved and does not build.

Comment: Yes the classes are public.

Comment: Yes; cleaned, eclipse restarted, windows restarted!

Comment: This 3 packages are different projects?
Do you have rebuild JAR to project, what is you want to import.

Comment: Sorry! I am unable to post an image due to low points.

Comment: Do you check "Problems" and "Error Log" windows?

Maybe there have some warring message, like the project miss a symbol or other.

Comment: No, its a single project. Its not a library or so, they are just separate packages in a project and I can not access classes defined in other packages.